# GoodBarber.com - Which control are they using?

Tags: ios, html

I was looking for the online app builders. I found www.goodbarber.com is a good platform to build the application with CMS.

I was wondering which controls are they using to build ios app?
Are those native controls or just HTML5?

I read theif FAQ which mentioned that they build the app in native ios. But not sure, what exactly they meant by that.

Comment: They probably use a mix of native controls and webviews. 

You're right though that mentioning that they build the app in native iOS isn't totally clear. They probably mean that the app is actually compiled ("built") in Xcode so that it can be submitted to the app store as a proper app. But this doesn't necessarily exclude the possibility that a lot of the application would use webviews.

Comment: @Adama yea true, and according to my knowledge, the chances of ios app getting rejected is more when you are using more webviews. I will not neglect the apple's strict app policies here.

Comment: Ehh, true that Apple wants you to use more native controls, but these businesses wouldn't exist if they couldn't get an app approved. I'd trust an app-builder service to get my app approved over myself building it all from scratch in most cases involving any complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a lot and going through lots of content online, finally i decided to go to **goodbarber.com**'s support.

I straight forward pushed my question in their contact us form and the reply i got is as follows.

> "Our apps are made native for iPhone & Android, so all sections (with
>   the exception of the HTML section) are native. Each app also comes
>   with an HTML5 version."

**Review:**

If you are looking for reviews from someone who has used it, you can go to [this link](https://www.previousmagazine.com/goodbarber-review).

**Alert:**

If you are looking for the content, review, questions, forum about goodbarber.com, you will probably wont find anything on google's first page. Just browse to next pages, you will be glad. And also [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Mobile-App-Builder) contains questions about the same.

The reason behind putting this alert is because i never go to 2nd page of google. ;-)

**PS:**

So the goodbarber.com uses native controls in their predefined templates.

**PPS:**

The performance of the templates were good and above my expectations. Although they do not provide the functionality to edit their template. And also they do not give you controls to put in the app directly, but just the templates.

Comment: I'm working for GoodBarber and I confirm that we use native components except in some cases to display some HTML formatting get from the source content.

Comment: @MathieuF thank you for confirming. You guys have done some good engineering there. Kudos!